# Installing Postgis on Ubuntu 12.04: unmet dependencies libgdal1

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu

After `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis` I got that massage:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: postgresql-9.1-postgis
>   : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed E:
>   Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tryed the `ubuntugis-unstable` and `ubuntugis-stable` repositories. I have QGIS 2.2 installed.

Comment: This might help you: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=libgdal1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This annoying issue occurs because libgdal was forked between libgdal1 and libgdal1h last year. Ubuntu GIS stable uses libgdal or libgdal1, Ubuntugis unstable uses libgdal1h.

> GDAL is a translator library for raster geospatial data formats.
>   As a library, it presents a single abstract data model to the
>   calling application for all supported formats. The related OGR
>   library (which lives within the GDAL source tree) provides
>   a similar capability for simple features vector data.

You will have to start from fresh.

Make sure you uninstall all software remnants of Ubuntugis Stable / Unstable. Uninstalling libgdal, libgdal1, libgdal1h will remove all software that depends on it. Then check your repos, make sure Ubuntugis Stable & Unstable isn't there.

Then add these repos for QGIS 2.2, Saga 2.1 and Postgres 9.3.3 & PostGIS 2.1.1.

http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu

Johan Van de Wauw's saga-gis repository

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

I usually install QGIS first then SAGA, Grass, PostgreSQL 9.3.3, PostGIS 2.1.1, postgresql-contrib-9.3 and finally pgAdmin3.

There are a few small issues. This will install Grass 6.4.3-2, which might not work from Processing in QGIS 2.2. Grass 6.4.3-3, provided by Ubuntugis Unstable, is supposed to fix the problem (but did not work for me on Ubuntu 13.10).

Also, only Ubuntu GIS Unstable provides pgRouting as far as I know (with PostgreSQL 9.1 & PostGIS 2.1.0). If you want pgRouting you will have to compile it from source, it only takes few minutes. If Configure complain that Postgresql-9.1 is not installed, install postgresql-server-dev-9.1 and try again.

Comment: How can I also install the latest version of GDAL?

Comment: This post confuses the heck out of me. Can you give me code samples I can work with? Nothing I did worked.

Comment: ps: I'm not using Ubuntu GIS. Just plain Ubuntu.

Comment: @picardo running into this now too... let's keep in touch as I'd like to repair the now broken installation instructions I wrote here: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt

Comment: For me, the installation works when I ssh into the server, but it fails when I use a build script, like a Dockerfile. There is no rhyme or reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Change the line in the Dockerfile that has the install to use 2.0 postgis:

```
RUN apt-get -y -q install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3 postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've sucessfully (without any broken dependencies) installed `postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0` instead of `postgresql-9.1-postgis`.